# Cannot assign factors by reference in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

As a minimal demonstration, say I want to copy factor column `y` from `dt2` to `dt1`:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(id = 1:2, x = 3:4, key = "id")
dt2 <- data.table(id = 2:3, y = factor(letters[1:2]), key = "id")

dt1[dt2, y := y]     # do copy

class(dt1$y)         # y ended up as integers in dt1
## "integer"

class(dt2$y)         # what y should be
## "factor"
```

`y` is not getting assigned as a factor. Any solutions?

Comment: This bug has been fixed in [v1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table).

Comment: With the latest version on github, I'm getting `Error in '[.data.table'(dt1, dt2, ':='(y, y)) :   i[2] is NA. Can't assign by reference to row 'NA'`. If I additionally specify `nomatch = 0`, I get `object 'CsubsetVector' not found`

Comment: Milo, I guess [#757](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/757) was filed by you. If so, all is well then I suppose :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase Arun:

- Bug has been fixed in [v1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)
- If you get `CsubsetVector` errors when
  installing from github, see [issue #757](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/757)